# How to delete instance class inside class

Tags: c++, class

Consider this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X {
  public:
    class Z {
      public:
        void f() {
          cout << "Z().f()" << endl;
        }
    };

    class Y {
      public:
        int A;
        Y(int x) {
          A = x;
        }

        int c() {
          return A;
        }
    };

    public:
      Z* z;

      // How to free Y instance ?
      Y* a(int x) {
        Y* y = new Y(x);
        return y;
      }

    public:
      X() {
        z = new Z();
      }

      ~X() {
        delete z;
      }
};

int main(void) {
  int a;
  X* x = new X();
  cout << "input :" << endl;
  cin >> a;
  cout << "result : " << x->a(a)->c() << endl;
  x->z->f();
  delete x;
  return 0;
}
```

While Z object can easily be freed on ~X(), i am curious how to free Y one ? Since i am not assigning any variable to hold its memory address.

Btw, what's the terminology for something like this ? x->a(a)->c()

Thank you. :)

Comment: If you don't know by who and when `y` should be deleted, you can use smart pointer. `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`

Comment: Unrelated: you are missing copy and assignment operators. Your class will cause undefined behavior when copied.

Comment: @pmr. You mean, assigning Y instance like Z one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// How to free Y instance ?
Y* a(int x) {
  Y* y = new Y(x);
  return y;
}
```

Well, the problem is that it is not clear from the function prototype *who* is responsible for deleting the instance. But since only the caller has a handle to the instance, then it should be the called's responsibility to delete. This should be well documented. But the best approach would be to use a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) with the right ownership semantics. In this case, `std::unique_ptr<Y>` seems like an appropriate match, and the mere fact of using it makes the intent clear, removing the need for documentation concerning ownership:

```
std::unique_ptr<Y> a(int x)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<Y>( new Y(x) );
}
```

Comment: @Aruman well, if the caller owns the resource, the old-school (and dangerous) way would be to document, stating that the caller is in charge of deleting. If class `X` owns the resource, then it should keep a handle to it, so that it can delete it in it's own destructor. So it all depends on the ownership semantics of the code, and that is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the memory from the function, so it is up to the caller to delete it:

```
X x;

Y *ptr = x.a(5);

delete ptr;
```

Hopefully you never have to do something like this. If you must then it's recommended that you use smart pointers like a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

```
std::unique_ptr<Y> a(int x) {
  return std::unique_ptr<Y>(new Y(x));
}
```

With this, you never have to worry about deleting the instance as the destructor of the pointer class holds that responsibility.